# When I go to root uri my images work, but when I go to base.com/controller/action uri they are broken images

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I've got a simple app that shows images when I go to the root uri which points to page#index.  Pictures work just fine this way, but when I go to /page/index the pictures are broken. What causes this?

routes.rb

```
root :to => "page#index"
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
```

When I view source and try to click on the images from /page/index I get:

```
Unknown action

The action 'assets' could not be found for PageController
```

Even if I put

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
```

before

```
root :to => "page#index"
```

it still doesn't render the images.

edit: since I'm getting a controller error.  Here is my page_controller.rb

```
class PageController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render "index"
  end
end
```

Comment: Seems like you're using a relative path for your assets, somehow, instead of an absolute path.  What's the code that generates the `<img>` tag?

Comment: @Xavier here is one img tag <img id="email" src="assets/email.png" alt="Contact" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha.  That `<img>` tag should look like this instead:

```
<img id="email" src="/assets/email.png" alt="Contact" />
```

Note the forward slash at the beginning of the `src` attribute.  With the slash, the browser will always try to pull the image from:

```
http://my.web.site/assets/email.png
```

But without it, you get a *relative* path, so the browser will try to get:

```
http://my.web.site/the/current/page/assets/email.png
```

Which doesn't exist.  Unless your current page is the root URL, which is why it works in that one circumstance.

Hope that helps!